# jQuery ajaxSend() working in FF but not Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This code is working fine in FF but not in Chrome.
`sendRequest();` Calls a `$.ajax()` request.

```
sendRequest('post')

$('#status').ajaxSend(function() {
  $(this).removeClass();
  $(this).html('Posting...');
});
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't work in Chrome?
Interestingly if I put an `alert()` at the end of the `ajaxSend()` I the 'Posting...' is added to the div but if the alert isn't there it doesn't change.

Here's the `$.ajax()` code as requested:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST",
  url: "ajaxRequest.php", 
  data: varString,
  dataType: "text",
  async:false,
  success: function(data){
    if(data == "1"){
    return true;
  }
  else{
   return false;    
  }
});
```

Comment: Putting ajaxSend before sendRequest works? http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/

Comment: You really should avoid doing synchronous calls, they lock up the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I can't leave a comment, but I need to ask: did you leave the ); at the end out of your code?  It looks like you ended the JSON set, but not the ajax method.

Comment: Ah, no worries.  Per epascarello's comment, is there any reason for this request to be synchronous?  Maybe try that to see if it works.  Otherwise my only other suggestion would be to put ajaxSend before the ajax calling function sendRequest.

Comment: I've changed it to async=true now and instead of relying on the returns from the ajax request I'm storing it in a var and reading it back when .ajaxSuccess() is triggered.
Now .ajaxSend() is working too. Thank you.